# Maven building jar of a war for another project's tests

Tags: java, maven, jar

PROJECT-A is a war. It has some code I want to use in the unit tests of PROJECT-B.

To do this, I think I need PROJECT-A to output a jar with it's classes. Here is an excerpt of the POM:

```
<project
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <parent>
      <groupId>au.com.name.redacted</groupId>
      <artifactId>PARENT-PROJECT</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
   </parent>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <artifactId>PROJECT-A</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   ... snip

   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>PROJECT-A-jar</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
```

When I run

```
 cd PROJECT-A
 mvn clean install
```

it outputs

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (PROJECT-A-jar) @ PROJECT-A ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Workspace\name\PROJECT-A\target\PROJECT-A-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ PROJECT-A ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Workspace\name\PROJECT-A\target\PROJECT-A-1.0.jar to C:\Users\myusername\.m2\repository\au\com\name\PARENT-PROJECT\PROJECT-A\1.0\PROJECT-A-1.0.war
```

I do see

```
D:\Workspace\name\PROJECT-A\target\PROJECT-A-1.0.jar
D:\Workspace\name\PROJECT-A\target\PROJECT-A-1.0.war
```

but I do not see the jar in in my repo - only the war.

```
C:\Users\myusername\.m2\repository\au\com\name\PARENT-PROJECT\PROJECT-A\1.0\PROJECT-A-1.0.war
```

So then in PROJECT-B I am attempting to have it get PROJECT-A as a dependency..

```
<project
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <parent>
      <groupId>au.com.name.redacted</groupId>
      <artifactId>PARENT-PROJECT</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
   </parent>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <artifactId>PROJECT-B</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
... snip
<dependency>
   <groupId>au.com.name.redacted</groupId>
   <artifactId>PROJECT-A</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And it fails with

```
     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT-B: Could not resolve dependencies for project au.com.name.redacted:PROJECT-B:war:1.0: Failure to find au.com.name.redacted:PROJECT-A:jar:1.0 in http://repo.server.com.au:8081/artifactory/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to pull the common code out into a new project with packaging type "jar" and have both your war and test project depend on it.

Comment: issue what you have is related to that, you are trying to have multiple packaging, which is generally wrong. you might get away with this by using `maven-assembly-plugin` but best solition will be as @NickWilson said, to extract common code to separate project and package it as jar

Comment: You may attach additional artifacts to your build by using the "Build Helper Maven Plugin" --> http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/ But, as @NickWilson says, you rarely need this if your projects are properly laid out.

Comment: I freely admit there may be a better way to layout this project, but it is large and complicated enough that I am not ready to try ripping out code into another project. We have 10 `pom.xml`s already, just to give an idea of the size of it. I am going home now.. on Monday I will have another look at any advice with fresh eyes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used war plugin for this purpose. Maybe this will help:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

It generates war and jar with sources after build which will be commited to local m2 repo. Configuration `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` is important.

In pom of project B use something like this (important part - `<classifier>classes</classifier>`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>projectA-groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA-artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>projectA-version</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I do already have a maven-war-plugin in the POM, but I don't think it generates JARs - I believe it is the reason that I am seeing WARs coming out.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough :) The configuration part '<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>' does the work for me.

Comment: Well, that's interesting.. now I see `PROJECT-A-1.0.classes.jar` in my repo, which is a step forward. Do you know how I tell Project-B to look for `PROJECT-A-1.0.classes.jar1` instead of `PROJECT-A-1.0.classes.jar`?

Comment: use standard dependency tag (groupId, artifactId, version) plus additional <classifier>classes</classifier> I've edited my answer.

Comment: Well, that works! I have some strange compilation errors now, but I am pretty sure that the classes are getting where I want them to be. Thank you very much. :)